# when I combine I am not able t see the delete button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, kendo-ui

- I moved my grid into popup. when i click three dots I need to show delete button
- I was able to see the delete button when it was alone.
- but when I combine I am not able t see the delete button.
- can you guys tell me how to fic it...
- providing my code and fiddle below.
- working fiddle
  http://jsfiddle.net/sureshatta/7brbws09/6/
- not working fiddle
  http://jsfiddle.net/XY7HT/61/

  ```
  <div id="grid"></div>
  <div class="pai-del-menu">Delete</div>


  <script id="delete-confirmation" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    kendoWindow.data("kendoWindow")
      .content($("#delete-confirmation").html())
      .center().open();

    $(document).on("click", "#playerDocumentOk", function(){
       pai_to_delete.remove();
   </script>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The `z-index` of the pop up is `z-index: 10011;` but your `.pai-del-menu` is only `z-index: 999;`. Just set it to above `10011`. For example `z-index: 10012;`.

Or you can set it dynamically, which I'd recommend as I realized the `z-index` is set dynamically:

```
$('.pai-del-menu').css({
  left: pai_x,
  top: pai_y,
  zIndex: parseInt($('.k-window').css('z-index')) + 1
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the z-index to 99999 like below:

```css
.pai-del-menu{
    padding: 4px;
    color: #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #eee;
    width: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,.2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12);
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99999;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```